# scala superclass reference with sub class object not calling subclass method

Tags: scala

Consider abstract class `Element` here is a super class for many subclasses like `ArrayElement` each have their own helper methods but with common `param` property

I need to call helper method `printValue` with `that` object. `check` method receive `ArrayElement` object in run time. Hence at run time, I hope there won't be any problem.

But, this code is not compiling, `that` object looking for `printValue` method in abstact class `Element` at compile time. It  forces me to declare `printValue` in `Element`

All the helper methods in `ArrayElement` need to be declared in super abstract class `Element`?

```
object ObjectTest {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val x = new ArrayElement(999).check(new ArrayElement(333))
    }
}
abstract class Element {
    val param : Int
    def printValue : String  // commenting this line throws error below
}
class ArrayElement(override val param : Int) extends Element {
    def check(that: Element)  = {
       this.printValue
       println(that.param)
       println(that.printValue)  // throws error -- **value printValue is not a member of org.mytest.challenges.Element**
    }
    def printValue = "value:" + param
}
```

Comment: change this line `println(that.x)` to `println(that.param)` hope this isn't a mistake?

Comment: Sorry. That's a typo. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**All the helper methods in ArrayElement need to be declared in super abstract class Element?**

Yes you have to have them in-case your argument to `def check` method is of type super class.

### OR

You can convert the incoming object into target type and call the method you want.

```
object ObjectTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     val x = new ArrayElement(999).check(new ArrayElement(333))
  }
}

abstract class Element {
    val param : Int
    // def printValue : String  // commenting this line throws error below
}
class ArrayElement(override val param : Int) extends Element {
   def check(that: Element)  = {
       this.printValue
       println(that.param)
       println(that.asInstanceOf[ArrayElement].printValue)
  }
  def printValue = "value:" + param
}
```

### OR

Use the `def printValue` method as default method in parent class.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

the that object is typed as Element, then if you remove printValue from Element it won't compile. Also, x is not a member of Element either. If the check method is going to be used by different subclasses from Element you may consider move it to Element as a protected method, it will be accessible from ArrayElement because it is extended.

```
object ObjectTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val x = new ArrayElement(999).check(new ArrayElement(333))
  }
}

abstract class Element {
  val param : Int
  def printValue : String

  protected def check(that: Element)  = {
    this.printValue
    println(that.param)
    println(that.printValue)
  }
}

class ArrayElement(override val param : Int) extends Element {
  def printValue = "value:" + param
}
```

On the other hand if check is going to be just an ArrayElement method, you should retype that to be ArrayElement

Comment: 'On the other hand if check is going to be just an ArrayElement method, you should retype that to be ArrayElement ' -- this is what I am looking for... thanks jpedreira and Puneeth reddy

Comment: @PraveenL also remember, that if you extend from an abstract class you have to implement everything defined in it.